# Double user-agent tag, "user-agent: user-agent: Mozilla/"

Tags: user-agent

I received a request from and amazon web service with the user-agent on the header as : "user-agent: user-agent: Mozilla/"
What does this mean?
Is this legit or an attempt at an exploit?
The request was redirected by the proxy server, could that have caused to add another user-agent tag?