# python user-agent xpath amazon

Tags: python, html, xpath, python-requests

I am trying to make a scan of the HTML in 2 requests.
at the first one, it's working but when I am trying to use another one,
The HTML I am trying to locate are not visible its getting it wrong.

```
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    page = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/ol/B00DZKQSRQ/ref=mw_dp_olp?ie=UTF8&condition=new, headers=headers)

newHeader = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36'}
pagePrice = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/ol/B01EQJU8AW/ref=mw_dp_olp?ie=UTF8&condition=new',headers=newHeader)
```

The first request works fine and gets me the good HTML.
The second request gives bad HTML.

I saw this package, but not success : 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-useragent

And I saw this topic not unaswered : 
[Double user-agent tag, "user-agent: user-agent: Mozilla/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598556/double-user-agent-tag-user-agent-user-agent-mozilla)

Thank you very much!

Comment: why is this tagged with `scrapy`?

Comment: removed this tag

Comment: Probably just a copy-paste error when posting, but you are missing a closing quotation mark at the end of the URL for the GET method.